# How to access the 'Comment' property of a fusion clip from a script on a tool inside that clip

Tags: davinci, blackmagic-fusion

In brief, how can I reference the 'Comment' property of a fusion clip from a script inside the clip. I imagine something like self.clip.comment perhaps.

In detail, I have added a `HorizontalLineReveal` to a composition. I want to set the text based on a text file. I have added a script to 'Start Render Scripts' in the uppertext_1_1_1 tool in the `HorizontalLineReveal` group that reads the text file and writes the value into the Text field. That all works.

However I want to be able to change the name of that file easily. So I thought I could put the text file name in the Comment field of the clip in the timeline and look at the Comment to get the filename. However I don't know how to reference the clip object or the property from the 'Start Render Scripts'.